# What's the difference between how @Component and @Repository / @Service annotations are processed?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I've stumbled upon a rather strange issue today with Spring 3.0:

There's an abstract class `A` and its concrete implementation `A_Impl`. `A_Impl` is annotated as `@Repository` and is auto-scanned by Spring (`<context:component-scan>` and `<context:annotation-config/>` are both declared in context). `A` and `A_Impl` are deployed in separate JARs (not sure if that matters). Everything works just fine.

Now, I was reviewing that code and `@Repository` didn't seem like a good fit semantically (the class in question has nothing to do with persistence) so - in my infinite wisdom - I've decided to change that to more generic `@Component`. Needless to say, everything blew up leaving me looking like a complete idiot. The error (which occurred during Spring context initialization) was Spring's `ClassPathResource.getInputStream()` method complaining about `A` class not being there (it is, I've manually checked; plus regular class loader finds it just fine)

**Nothing else has changed**. If I swap `@Component` for `@Repository` context initializes, if I swap them back it doesn't with the above error. [Spring documentation claims there's no difference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) between `@Component` and `@Repository` which is clearly a damned lie :-) So I wonder - what **is** the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using `@Component` without troubles.

The only thing (although not-so-intelligent one) that comes to my mind as possibility is that your `@Component` might not be the spring one. Tapestry, for example, has an annotation named the same way. Other frameworks may also have it. So check your imports.

Comment: Good point, but it's most definitely Spring's `@Component`. Were it not, it would simply not get picked up - but it is and it blows up the   context in the process.

Comment: hm. Is the exception the one that "no bean of type .. is found", or another ?

Comment: No, the exception is `FileNotFoundException` thrown from `ClassPathResource.getInputStream()` because class loader can't open an `InputStream` for `A.class`. I'm not as much concerned with resolving this error per se - I'm reasonably sure it's Spring's bug and I'll step through the code when I get a chance and confirm it - as I'd like to know how (and why) @Repository and @Component processing differs.

Comment: that's odd indeed. it seems that @Repositry, @Controller and @Service are themselves annotated with @Component, and there is a TypeFilter that registers only @Component. Could you give the whole stacktrace - I happen to have the spring sources checked-out (for situations like these)

Comment: I've changed it back to `@Component` and did a clean build to get a stack trace and it works now :-) I guess it must have been some odd build artifact throwing class loader off. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hehe :) Good to know there is no problem in those annotations, I've always been somewhat suspicious to them (although using them excesssively)

Answer (score 0):

```
|Annotation  | Meaning                                             |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| @Component | generic stereotype for any Spring-managed component |
| @Repository| stereotype for persistence layer                    |
| @Service   | stereotype for service layer                        |
| @Controller| stereotype for presentation layer (spring-mvc)      |
```

Use of `@Service` and `@Repository` annotations are important from database connection perspective.

1. Use `@Service` for all your web service type of DB connections
2. Use `@Repository` for all your stored proc DB connections

If you do not use the proper annotations, you may face commit exceptions overridden by rollback transactions. You will see exceptions during stress load test that is related to roll back JDBC transactions.

Comment: Could someone clarify what is meant by "web service type of DB connections" and "stored proc DB connections"?  I'm wondering if Satish misinterpreting "service layer" as referring to web services.