# Can't get@Autowired to work with beans

Tags: java, spring

I'm currently just starting out with Spring and trying to get the hang of it. But I've run into a problem: My @Autowired keeps failing.

In my `spring.xml` I've got this:

```
<!--Handle @Autowired-->
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan  base-package="org.MYPROJECT">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

When running some tests it fails with this (I'm only showing the last exception as its the most important)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.quackbot.dao.AdminDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 50 more
```

So I try to fix it by adding the bean manually to the config

```
<bean id="AdminDAO" class="org.quackbot.dao.hibernate.AdminDAOHibernate">
</bean>
```

Run it again, now I get this

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.quackbot.dao.AdminDAO] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [adminDAOHibernate, AdminDAO]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
    ... 50 more
```

Seems I just can't win when using Spring... First it complains that the beans don't exist, when specifying them it complains that there's too many. What's going on? Why can't it load the correct beans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an annotation in your dao?

Something like @Repository or @Component right above the class to tell Spring this needs to be picked up when scanning your base package?

Comment: Wow, can't believe that caused all this. Didn't have @Component on my DAO's. None of the tutorials I followed mentioned this and Spring's tutorial glazed over the importance of it. Quick question though: Should I use `@Repository` instead? `@Repository` sounds like the class caches the fetched objects and does things to them, while in my DAO classes the methods are simple Hibernate criteria queries

Comment: I am using @Repository and doing the same thing with hibernate queries and it works fine for me.  There is a SO question on this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923891/whats-the-difference-between-how-component-and-repository-service-annotatio that might help a little.

Answer (score 1):

This is more than enough, no other XML configuration is needed in your case:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.quackbot"/>
```

Secondly, make sure `AdminDAOHibernate` implements `AdminDAO`.

Last but not least, double check that the field annotated with `@Autowired` is of type `AdminDAO` (interface).

Last piece of advice: add default constructor to `AdminDAOHibernate` and place place some logging statement there or put breakpoint. There should be only one invocation of this constructor, although it gets tricky when class proxies are involved.

Comment: Your version of component-scan gives NullPointerExceptions when accessing the autowired field, which is why I did it the way I said. Second, AdminDAOHibernate does implement AdminDAO (does the presence generics effect anything?). Field is AdminDAO as well (also with generics). With the constructor, it doesn't seem to be called at all, the logging statement isn't running. Seems there's a whole bunch of problems here

Answer (score 1):

Is this a Spring MVC app? One way or another, I'm guessing you have two separate Spring contexts, whether you know it or not. In one context, you have a dependency on your AdminDAO, but it isn't available, which causes your first exception. Your other context also has a dependency on AdminDAO which is already satisfied, but when you manually add another AdminDAO bean, that fails because there are two of them.

Comment: I guess this shows my ignorance of Spring as I create a new context for each Test class in TestNG's @BeforeClass (all tests extend a GenericTest that provide useful methods and configuration)... Didn't know that was such a bad thing.

Comment: Changed to all tests extending `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and using `@ContextConfiguration`, and got back to square one with those same exceptions. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just the same thing: you probably have a context starting up somewhere that expects to have an AdminDAO, but you're not including the context file that defines it. You'll have to add details to your question for a better diagnosis, like what test is it failing on, what context file(s) do/does that test use, and maybe more of the logs surrounding the exception. Btw, don't add a manual definition of the DAO. That's definitely not the right solution.

Comment: Sorry, newbie mistake. See @blong's anser. Essentially I didn't have `@Component` on the DAO's, something none of the tutorials I was following mentioned and Spring's tutorial glazed over the importance of. Tough issue to figure out though

Comment: If that's the case, how did you get the "expected single matching bean but found 2" error when you manually added a DAO bean to the XML?

Comment: I have no idea. I got 0 with no manual declaration and 2 with declaration. Maybe Spring didn't see the class at first until I declared them?

Comment: Doesn't work that way. I'm glad you found a way to make it work, but I suspect that you've only masked the underlying problem. Keep this error in mind if you have problems with this DAO in the future.

Answer (score -1):

@Autowired using annotations

@Repository("ExampleDao")
public class ExampleDaoImpl implements ExampleDao

@Service("ServiceExample")
public class ExampleServiceImpl implements ExampleService

@Controller
public class ExampleController

@Autowired
    private ExmpleService ServiceExample;